# Как сделать чтобы результат выводился в многострочном текстовом поле?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#1.6 Разложить целое число на простые множители.
#Вывести на экран все простые множители (в порядке возрастания) и их порядки.
from tkinter import *


def func(event):
    
    N = int(ent.get())
    F = N
    for i in range(2, F):
        if F%i==0:
            d=0 
            for B in range(2, i):
                if i % B ==0:
                    d+= 1
            if d == 0:
                por = 0 
                while N % i ==0:
                    por += 1
                    N=N//i
                
                #print("делитель",i,"порядок",por)
                s=f"делитель {i}, порядок {por}"
                
                
                tex = Text(root,width=40,
                           font="Verdana 12",
                           wrap=WORD) 
                

                #tex.insert(1.0, s)
                
root = Tk()   #главный экран

root.title('1.6 Разложение числа на простые множители')#название главного окна
root.geometry('400x175')


   


lab1 =  Label(root, text = 'Разложить целое число на простые множители. \n Вывести на экран все простые множители \n (в порядке возрастания) и их порядки.', font = 'Arial 12')

lab2 = Label(root, text = 'Введите n:', font = 'Arial 12')
ent = Entry(root) 

but = Button(root) 
but["text"]="Разложить"
but.bind('<Button-1>', func)

tex = Text(width = 15, height = 5, font = 'Arial 12')


lab1.pack()
lab2.pack()
ent.pack()
but.pack()
tex.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Создать текстовое поле один раз, потом добавлять в него строки через метод insert, а не создавать постоянно новое. Т.е. правильнее делать через закомментированную у вас строку `tex.insert(1.0, s)`, только она вставляет в начало. Чтобы добавляло в конец - нужно заменить 1.0 на "end". Только нужно убрать создание нового Text выше этой строки.

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручили)